# JSLink - retrieve user details from a string field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, jslink

I have a SharePoint-Field of type `string`, that contains a value such as:

> domain\usertoken

From the string I would like to retrieve the person - and from the person I would like to retrieve some user data, such as firstname and lastname.

Is there any way to ensure the user beyond the string in JSLink-context and then retrieve some user data?

My latest (failed) attempt looks like this (the relevant part is in `function CustomFieldAktuellerGenehmiger(ctx)`):

```
(function () {


    var globalOverrideCtx = {
        Templates: {
            OnPreRender:function(renderCtx){
                var visibleFields = ['Status','Aktueller_Genehmiger'];
                var fieldsCount = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field.length;
                for (var fieldIndex = fieldsCount - 1; fieldIndex >= 0; fieldIndex--) {
                    var field = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[fieldIndex];                 
                    if(visibleFields.indexOf(field.Name)==-1){
                        renderCtx.ListSchema.Field.splice(fieldIndex, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            Fields: {
                'Aktueller_Genehmiger':{
                    'View': CustomFieldAktuellerGenehmiger
                },  
            }
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(globalOverrideCtx);
})();

function CustomFieldAktuellerGenehmiger(ctx){
    var return3;

    var user = ctx.CurrentItem.Aktueller_Genehmiger;

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();

    // This currently returns: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined
    var user = context.web.EnsureUser("cznet\zoshaeh");


    return3 = testuser;

    return return3;

}
```

This currently returns:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined

I don't know how to get the relevant context in JSLink.

**Update: I have also tried:**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var user = context.web.EnsureUser("domain\usertoken");
console.log(user);
})
```

This returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EnsureUser' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use this to wrap your code uesd ClientContext.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){})
```

**Updated:**

This code I have used for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
  var testCase=function(callback){      
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        clientContext.load(user);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){     
        callback(null,user.get_loginName()) ;          
        },function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());})
    }

    }) 
</script>
```

similar issue:
https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get_current-of-undefined/

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Where would be the correct place in my code to set this line? Do I have to wrap the complete function: `function CustomFieldAktuellerGenehmiger(ctx){}`.

Comment: check the update

Comment: Thanks for the update Amos. I still don't seem to get it properly - I'm sorry. I have updated my question with an attempt I have done in reference to your answer.

Comment: Try to use context.get_web().ensureUser('contoso\name') directly.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, do you know any way how to make the ensured user accessible outside the custom function `executeFunc(){ }`? I tried to define a variable outside this function, then overwriting this variable inside and accessing it outside the function again. But it always takes my by default set value.

Comment: executeQueryAsync is an asynchronous method,the variable may not be assigned value before being used.You couls try to use setTimeOut or run executeQueryAsync synchronously.Demo:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134932/how-to-call-executequeryasync-to-behave-synchronously